# Picocli: how to access subcommands after parseWithHandler(new RunAll(), args)?

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, picocli

I have a command with subcommands, which are registered declaratively, and I'm interested in using this style of command line processing:

```java
List<Object> parsed = commandLine.parseWithHandler(new RunAll(), args);
```

However, for unit testing purposes, I want to access the subcommand object to see if it has the correct options set, etc. Is there a way to access the subcommand object when using `RunAll`?

*(See also https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/489 )*

Answer (score 0):

In the unit test, if you have access to the `CommandLine` object, you can call `CommandLine.getParseResult()`. You can query this object to see which options were matched. You can also descend into the subcommands with `ParseResult.hasSubcommand()` and `ParseResult.subcommand()`.